# Best way to set and get number of pages of printed products

Tags: java, performance, e-commerce

I am looking for the best way to set and get the number of pages of
   multiple printed products for a eCommerce Web.

The current application is using the approach where:

- it will open the file in the folder it stores and
- calculate the number of pages whenever user add the product to cart.

I think this might cause performance issue.

Is setting the product pages in cms a better option or there is a better way in setting and getting the number of pages of the products?